# Nintex Mask Context item URL

Tags: sharepoint-2010, nintex-workflow

I have created an email to send a notification when a list item has been modified. 
The email should send a link to the item using Context Item URL. So far I have the email ending the URL , but is there anyway I can mask it so it just displays a hyperlink "View Here" rather than the whole url string ?

I have been trying for hours and have no Idea how to do this.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual as soon as I posted this I found the answer.
This turned out to be a peculiarity with SharePoint where it didn’t give any prompt or indications that you had to double click not just select an item.

1 Insert link 
2 Place place you mouse in Address
3 Double Click the Context Item URL
4 Field Populates & enter the display name.
[image: Walkthrough]